# Django : Raw query fetching values from table

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, pgadmin

```
job = jobs.objects.raw('select j.*, v.ip, v.id , v.name from jobs_jobs as j,clientadmin_virtualmachine as v where (j.ip_id)::int = v.id order by j.date desc')
```

While executing this query in pgAdminIII it returns result from both tables as per the query but when I use the same in django view it fetches result from first table only, ignoring the **v.ip, v.id , v.name** field values.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

When you use raw queries, Django, will add the extra fields automagically to instances of your model (in this case Job). However there is always confusion when columns names overlap. Which column get's mapped to which field? To avoid this you should explicitly name all columns from the secondy tables involved in the query. Something like this:

```
select j.*, v.ip, v.id as vid , v.name as vname from jobs_jobs as
  j,clientadmin_virtualmachine as v where (j.ip_id)::int = v.id 
  order by j.date desc
```

Now you will have a field in each job instance named `vid` and `vname`. You do not need to have a model created for the `virtualmachine` table.

Having said all this, the above query is something that can be easily written using the ORM so you probably ought to avoid a raw query here

Comment: I'm completely new to this. Help me doing this (j.ip_id)::int = v.id  in ORM.

Comment: No that is a different question. Please try my answer, if it works, mark it as correct. Then post a new question. with your models. And this raw query and ask how one can be translated into the other.

Answer (score 0):

the `jobs` manager only returns fields from its mapped table. You need to create a model for the `clientadmin_virtualmachine` table as well and use it in a `ForeignKey`